# Detect what link is clicked without JS and GET

Tags: php

**HTML:**

```
<a id="firstid" class="someclass-one anotherclass" href="somelink.php">01</a>
<a id="secondid" class="someclass-two anotherclass" href="somelink.php">02</a>
<a id="thirdid" class="someclass-three anotherclass" href="somelink.php">03</a>
```

Is there a way to detect with PHP(without JS) and without manipulating the link it self in HTML code(for `$_GET` use) what specific link is clicked?

Comment: No, simply no, you can't do that.

Comment: @Jimbot Yes I can. Detecting by classname, for example. But this isn't right for me, I see this as some ugly way. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I'm looking for more appropriate way to make this

Comment: I'd love to see the php code that does that, I don't believe you can

Comment: @Jimbot is right you cant, the class is not sent with the request, you need to add a param to the url e.g `somelink.php?trk=one`

Comment: The classname or id are only available on the client side. The server side (PHP) only know the url you try to get and the header from the browser. So if you don't use javascript you wont be able to pass them to the server.

Answer (score 0):

**No there is no way to to that.**

You either have to use PHPs get variables and add a key/value to your url or by using javascript. Keep in mind tho, that JavaScript solutions may be altered easily by users, whilst PHP you can validate on your server to prevent bad user input.